# Does JUnit Jupiter's extension auto detection prevent finding tests?

Tags: maven-surefire-plugin, junit5

We recently updated to `maven-surefire-plugin` v2.22.1 and `junit` v5.4.0 when we found this error:
**[ERROR]** Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.22.1:test (default-test) on project xxx: **No tests were executed!**  (Set -DfailIfNoTests=false to ignore this error.) -> [Help 1]

After several checks, we found that we had to:

1. delete this line from our configuration:
   `junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled = true`
2. and also include this one to keep using parallel execution:
   `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent`

For the second point, it's clarified in the user guide, but we have no idea about the first point... can someone explain what could be the reason? could this be a bug?

Thanks!

Comment: What happens with the latest 3.x version of Surefire and keeping auto detection enabled?

Comment: Hi @Sormuras you are right! with 3.0.0-M3 AND also including ´junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default = concurrent´ I don't need to remove the autodetection. Thanks!

Comment: Fine! Will rephrase my question as an answer. Feel free to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Maven Surefire 3.x

Maven Surefire version `3.x` provides better support regarding the JUnit Platform. Please upgrade Surefire to `3.0.0-M3` or higher.

#### JUnit Jupiter Parallel Test Execution

To enable parallel test execution you need to perform two configuration steps:

1. Set `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.enabled` to `true`.
2. Either set `junit.jupiter.execution.parallel.mode.default` to `concurrent` to activate **concurrent** execution mode for all test containers (including classes, test templates and dynamic containers) *OR* use the `@Execution(CONCURRENT)` annotation on all test classes that shall take part in parallel test execution.

For more details, see https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#writing-tests-parallel-execution

Comment: Bad news... I recently found that updating to 3.x was not the fix... I accidentally set the value to "true " instead of "true" which is the same as "false" and therefore it worked. But when I fixed this, the original error came back (No tests were executed!) so it really looks an issue.

Comment: Mh, bad luck. Please open an issue at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SUREFIRE -- thanks in advance